# How do I pass a string concatenation to the source command in vim?

Tags: vim

My current .vimrc includes these two lines, which are a bit redundant

```vim
let g:opamshare = "/home/hugo/.opam/system/share"
source /home/hugo/.opam/system/share/vim/syntax/ocp-indent.vim
```

Is there a way to use the value of the `opamshare` variable in the `source` command on the second line? I tried

```vim
source g:opamshare . "/vim/syntax/ocp-indent.vim"
```

but that gives me a `E172: Only one file name allowed` error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From vim doc:

```
:so[urce] {file}        Read Ex commands from {file}.
```

You need to pass only one `file` as argument to `source` command.
It doesn't treat argument as `string`, so you cannot use `.(dot)` to concat strings.

---

Try this:

```
:exec printf('source %s/%s', g:opamshare, 'vim/syntax/ocp-indent.vim')
```

Comment: I was hoping the answer wouldn't involve abusing string concatenation but I guess `execute` is the only way then. The printf is more readable than what I had in mind though, thanks!

Comment: you can also use `.(dot)` to concat.

Comment: `execute` is the only way. The printf is superfluous though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an environment variable as a work-around:

```vim
    let $OPAMSHARE="/home/hugo/.opam/system/share"
    source $OPAMSHARE/vim/syntax/ocp-indent.vim
```

See `:help expr-env` and `:help expression-syntax`.